# Solve Poisson Equation for 3d mesh

Tags: julia, differentialequations.jl

I am trying to solve the poisson-equation div v = -curl w to simulate Incompressible Flow of a mesh in 3 dimensional space.

*What I did:*

I found the [ODE example](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/v2.0.0/tutorials/ode_example.html) and how to solve the [Poisson Equation](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/v2.0.0/tutorials/fempoisson_example.html).

*My problems/questions are:*

- How to define -curl w as the differential equation in julia with the help of DifferentialEquation.jl? How to specify the 3 dimensional cross product (*curl*)?

Comment: nothing in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPEqYtEd-zY either

Comment: Those FEM tools in DifferentialEquations.jl have long since been removed. I'll be doing a workshop at the next JuliaCon describing how to do PDE solving in Julia though. In the meantime, there are discretization tools like JuliaFEM and JuAFEM which can help you get what you need.

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/KristofferC/JuAFEM.jl/pull/220 might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Those FEM tools in DifferentialEquations.jl have long since been removed. I'll be doing a workshop at the next JuliaCon describing how to do PDE solving in Julia though. In the meantime, there are discretization tools like JuliaFEM and JuAFEM which can help you get what you need.